# [C++} Not sure if this is even possible

Tags: c++, function, class

I'm trying to find the average net pay for a payroll program. What I'm wondering is it possible to create an array from the outputted tabular data and use the array to calculate the average? Or do I have to do this a different way? My code thus far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class employee {
    ifstream fin;
    char employeeid[12];
    char employeename[20];
    char martialstatus;
    int hoursworked, overtime;
    double hourlyrate, overtimepay, regularpay, grosspay, taxrate, taxamount, netpay, average;
    void calculateGrosspay();
    void calculateTax();
    void calculateNetpay();
    void printHeadings();
    void printData();
    double findAverage();
    void printAverage();
public: employee();
        ~employee();
        void printReport(); };

employee::employee(){
    fin.open(payrollData.txt);
}; //Constructor

employee::~employee() {
    fin.close(); } //Destructor

void employee::calculateGrosspay() {
    if (hoursworked > 40) {
        overtime = hoursworked - 40;
        regularpay = hoursworked * hourlyrate;
        overtimepay = overtime * (hourlyrate * 1.5);
        grosspay = regularpay + overtimepay;
    }
    else grosspay = hoursworked * hourlyrate;
} //Calculate gross pay function

void employee::calculateTax() {
    taxrate = .30;
    taxamount = grosspay*taxrate;
} // calculate tax function

void employee::calculateNetpay() {
     netpay = grosspay - taxamount;
} //Calculate net pay

void employee::printHeadings() {
     cout << setw(45) << "-Employee Payroll Report-" << endl;
    cout << "____________________________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "NAME    ID    HW OT    RT-PAY    OT-PAY   Gross    Tax     NetPay" << endl;
    cout << "____________________________________________________________" << endl;
} // print table headings


void employee::printData() {
     cout << setprecision(2) << setiosflags(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint);
     cout << setw(6) << employeename << setw(12) << employeeid << setw(4) << hoursworked << setw(3) << overtime << setw(8) << regularpay << setw(8)
    << overtimepay << setw(8) << grosspay << setw(8) << taxamount << setw(8) << netpay << endl;
} // print data



void employee::printReport() {
    int i = 0;
    printHeadings();
    while (fin >> employeename >> employeeid >> hoursworked >> hourlyrate) {
        calculateGrosspay();
        calculateTax();
        calculateNetpay();
        printData();
        i++;
    }
}

double employee::findAverage() {

    return average;
}

void printAverage() {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The average netpay is" << average << endl;
}

void main() {
    employee.printReport();
    employee.findAverage();
    employee.printAverage();
}
```

So after the program has printed the data to the console I want to find the average of the net pays and print it to the console. Best way to do this?

Comment: You should probably store the data you read in an array structure (like vector) and then just run your report on the data in the vector -- or query the database the data originated from

Comment: Downvote for stupid title.

Comment: Thank you Soren for the help, and thank you EJP for being a troll.

Comment: @swindleNswoon: What EJP is saying is that your title should communicate something about the nature of your problem. The current title is completely useless.

Comment: Kundor, I respond really well to constructive criticism. I basically copied and pasted this post from Reddit, but I will try to be less broad about my titles in the future. Your comments gives me something I can work off of and improve upon. This is not the case with EJP. For a guy who claims to have the CSV that he does, he seems rather unprofessional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need a vector like Soren mentioned. If you're trying to get some averages for all employees (which that's what I assume you're trying to do), then let's say we're going to try and get an average for gross pay.

You'll need a vector global, like such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<double> netPayList;
double globalAverage;
```

You'll then need to add information to the vector when GrossPay is calculated as such:

```
void employee::calculateNetpay() 
{
     netpay = grosspay - taxamount;

     netPayList.push_back(netpay);    
}
```

Finally, we can calculate the average in `employee::findAverage()`, we should also probably use a for loop for this as well, and in my opinion we should ditch the public function of "employee" and switch that over to a traditional function, since we are trying to get the average for many "employee" instances. The average calculation will now look like this:

```
double findAverage()
{
        for (int iterator = 0; iterator < netPayList.size(); iterator++)
        {
             average += netPayList[iterator];
        }

        globalAverage /= netPayList.size();

        return globalAverage;
 }
```

Anyway, that's basically the gist of it. Keep working on your stuff, but also I would suggest that you title your questions better. Someone with more gumption and SO privileges than I will most likely edit your OP.

Comment: Ah, okay great thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question!